# Java how to check if website block from Network Adminstrator

Tags: java

Is it possible with Java code to check if any URL or website is blocked by Network Admin ?
Suppose I am logging in by my **Gmail** credentials to my website. Now if I open the website in a network where **Gmail** is blocked, how would I tell the user that this website is blocked in your network and so you cannot login from **Gmail**.

Comment: AFAIK the best you can get is "something went wrong and I can't connect to gmail.com". You'd probably get a timeout, to be more specific, but there's no "blocked by network admin" error.

Comment: That will not happen, take a example, in my office gmail is blocked but still all the website where option is availble to login with gmail credentials, I am able to login. Currently I am logged in to Stackflow with gmail credentials.So it should not matter whether it blocked by admin.

Comment: @AnshuKunal How can it be possible you can login in Stackoverflow through Gmail when it is blocked in your office .Even Stackoverflow forward you gmail Login page for login ? And if Gmail block redirect will show exception I Just tried with Facebook Login of Stacjoverflow as Facebook block in my Office i got error "Cananot display this page"

Comment: @askkuber sorry for confusion, I meant to say using google login.

Answer (score 2):

The following piece of code will do what you want , but its a BEST Guess

```
try {
    URL myURL = new URL("http://example.com/");
    URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
    myURLConnection.connect();
} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
    // new URL() failed
    // ...
} 
catch (IOException e) {   
    // openConnection() failed
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So before calling openid API i have to call this piece of code if no error then go forward otherwise show some Message?

Comment: Exactly , wrap this in a method with the url as a parameter , again this may not work as in the second answer you may be forwarded to an administration page. You will then need to read that page and decide if it is blocked.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find out if a site is blocked by your network administrator, you need to check the content received :

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.gmail.com");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

    connection.connect();

    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    while(is.available()>0) {
        is.read(b);
        System.out.println(new String(b));
    }
```

You should analyze the content from input stream and based on that you can decide. I tried it and it gave me the HTML page set by network admin.

If your company using any proxy than you need to set following as well:

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "<proxy address>");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "<proxy port>");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but it could be very hard to analyze the InputStream because in different Network,there could be different strategy to block a website Some showing some message some not showing anything

Comment: yup you are right, to overcome this you need to comeup with the common pattern among these admin pages.