# How to check if a website is blocked or not programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I need to check if a web site is blocked by ISP or not to make the right decision in my android app.
How can I do that?

Comment: You can probably just make an `HttpURLConnection` service call and check the error code, assuming it would be set correctly.

Comment: please define what do you mean by *website is blocked*.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko: Some websites are blocked in iran and their users need to use VPNs to access them. such as facebook, twitter, telegram, etc. I'm going to know if a certain website is blocked or not.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I'll test your solution.

Comment: first define, what exactly do you mean by **blocked**. That may mean different things. The way to solve your problem depends on the way you define it. How do you know in real life if the web site is blocked?

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali Please answer to the above comment.  We need to know exactly what condition you are checking for.  Is it status code 401/501/502?  Or, is it something else?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko it will be redirected to another webpage which display a message to users that says something like THIS SITE IS BLOCKED,

Comment: then you may check if you get a 30X code (moved temporally/permanently), which means *redirect*, and check the redirect url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that we are talking about the typical way that websites are blocked<sup>1</sup>; i.e. by just dropping packets from your device destined for the website's IP address.

It is not possible to distinguish a website being blocked by your ISP from a number of other things, including:

- the website being blocked by something on your device,
- access being blocked by the website itself, or
- the website or the website's host or the website's ISP or some part of the internet or your ISP being down ... in various senses.

This is not an Android limitation.  It is inherent to the way that "the internet" works.   Packets are sent.  If they fail to reach the intended destination, there is no way to be absolutely sure what caused that to happen.

In short, you need to rethink your app's design so that it doesn't need to do this at all.

---

<sup>1 - Other possible ways might be to return an HTTP response with specific response code, a specific header or a response body with specific content.  But this isn't tractable either, since different ISPs will do this differently.  Indeed, it not possible to distinguish this kind of ISP blocking from blocking by other agents ... or in some cases from errors that are not attributable to blocking at all.</sup>

Comment: Finally, that is what I was trying to tell in the comment section of my answer. But people keep on downvoting my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, if you get a response as true it is allowed,

```
public boolean isSiteBlocked() {
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        urlc.connect();
        if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            return new Boolean(true);
        }
// also check different code for down or the site is blocked, example
        if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 521) {
         // Web server of the site is down
            return new Boolean(false);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return false;
}
```

**UPDATE**

If the site is down or the server is down it has to be handled according to requirements

Comment: ...OP doesnt want to check if internet is working.. Wants to know if a particular site is blocked by ISP

Comment: If the given site is not blocked he will get a 200 response. If is blocked it will receive an error response. I have tested it, please check the entire code.

Comment: the question is about `java`. Your answer is definitely not Java.

Comment: Probably I know why all they complain. Your code will show, whether the web site is accessible right now on the device, which is not exactly the same if the web site is blocked by ISP. There are different reasons why the web site may be inaccessible, but not blocked. For example, web site might be just down, but not blocked. In this case your code will not work.

Comment: If the website is down or inaccessible, a separate check has to made which is not in the scope of the question. The downvotes are not justifiable according to me.

Comment: @AarthTandel You've been attacked, possibly by a group of zombies or trolls +1.

Comment: the problem is if the site is **not blocked** but **down**, your code will show that it is **blocked**, which is wrong.

Comment: If the site is down, he will recieve a different error code which the user has to handle. And when the site is blocked another error code is reveiceved.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen theses group of zombies or trools wont back down.

Comment: But that is not handled in your code. Your code checks only whether the code is 200 or not. and as I said, `if the site is not blocked but down, your code will show that it is blocked, which is wrong`

Comment: Updated the code, there are many as such error the use user has to fix. Which, is not with the scope of the question

Answer (score -2):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23881591/6349833)

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.gmail.com");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

connection.connect();

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

byte[] b = new byte[1024];
if (is.available()> 1024) {
   // do something
}
```

The unblocked site should contain more than 1024 characters. It only contains "This site is blocked by ..."

Comment: you can't just copy another answer.

Comment: i didn't. See is.available part, and i also included the link. I thought you couldn't only answer via links, so there was sample code.

Comment: you are right, you shouldn't answer with links. You should mark a question a duplicate instead.